# SQL - Automatically adjust Where clause to previous month in YYYY-MM format

Tags: sql, teradata, alteryx, yearmonth

(This is all steps in containers within an Alteryx flow that is connecting to a Teradata source)

My SQL is incredibly rusty as it's been almost 8 years since I've needed to use it.  I know this is a quite basic question.  Basically I have several queries that need to be manually adjusted monthly to shift the month. in YYYY-MM format.  They look like this:

Is the main one where I just adjust one backwards one month

```
select DB.TABLE.field1, DB.TABLE.Year_month
from DB.TABLE
where DB.TABLE.Year_month = '2023-01'
```

This is the secondary one where I adjust one backwards one month, and the others are same month or plus a month or more.

```
and A.B_MONTH in ('2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01','2023-05-01') 
and B.Year_month = '2023-01'
```

How do I adjust the where clause to always be the needed relative references?

Any help is greatly appreciated

I tried using concat but it choked for some reason.

Comment: Hi - have a look at the DateTimeAdd function documented here: https://help.alteryx.com/20223/designer/datetime-functions

Comment: `DateTimeFormat([DateTime_Out],"%Y-%m")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select DB.TABLE.field1, DB.TABLE.Year_month
from DB.TABLE
where DB.TABLE.Year_month = DATE_FORMAT( NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m')
```

I don't understand your second need, but you can do it similar to my response.
Just play with the NOW() - INTERVAL X.

Comment: Thank you for that.  It didn't like it unfortunately.  "Syntax Error: Data Type "Now" does not match a defined type name"

Comment: @fruehling  take a look at the doc [link](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2019/Built-In-Functions/NOW/Example). You can try CURRANT_DATE() too instead of NOW(). did you write it in capital letters? May be it is case-sensitive.

Comment: This question is tagged "teradata" not "sql-server".

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic stuff.  `ADD_MONTHS` to move your month around, `TO_CHAR` for your desired format.
To get the previous month:

`select to_char(add_months(current_date,-1),  'YYYY-MM')`